# how do I solve an error in asking question in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am fairly familiar in Prolog language. was writing a DSS in prolog and I encountered the error

```
pl:96:12: syntax error: . or operator expected after expression
    1 error(s)
```

personally I don't see where the error is
here is a part of  the code where the compiler is indicating the error

```
ask(Question) :-
    write('Do you have ?:'),
    write(Question),
    write('?,y/n '),
    read(Response), nl,
    ( (Response == yes ; Response == no)
    ->
    assert(yes(Question)) ;
    assert(no(Question)), fail).

:- dynamic yes/1,no/1.
```

Comment: `:- dynamic yes/1,no/1.` is SWI-Prolog syntax. "syntax error: . or operator expected after expression" sounds like GNU Prolog. You may be having a compatibility issue.

Comment: Write `:- dynamic(( yes/1, no/1 )).` instead of the last line. You are using GNU, not SWI (as you had it tagged).

Comment: ... and, use rather `asserta/1`, also note that both `yes` and `no` will assert `yes(Q)` which is most probably not what you intended.

Comment: That 96 in "pl:96:12: syntax error:" is the line number of the error.